# Windows 8 style apps don't work over VPN connections

Tags: windows-8, vpn, windows-store-app

I'm using a VPN connection to my corporate network and am trying to use some Windows-8 style (Modern, Metro, whatever) apps and they are unable to see the network connection when using VPN. This is the case for all Windows 8 apps except for Mail and Calendar. What could be causing this issue, and is there a workaround for this bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. Microsoft has released a hotfix for this issue. Learn more about this at KB article 2797356, which you can find here: [Network status is "Limited" when you use a force tunneling VPN connection in Windows 8](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2797356)